# I am searching for an idiom for a chaotic bedroom

Tags: idiom-request

I am searching for an idiom for a chaotic and irregular bedroom. Consider a situation that your mother enters your bedroom and encounters with that scene. At that situation, what does she say?

Comment: She might say "This place is a **tip**!" (A [tip](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tip) being a rubbish dump, UK.)

Comment: What do you mean by *idiom*, precisely? I can think of several words, such as **pigsty**, but they are not actually idioms.

Comment: Perhaps not PC but "It looks as though a bomb has gone off in here!"

Comment: What a [**shambles**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/shambles)!

Comment: All of them are OK to me, thanks. @WeatherVane

Comment: My then wife used to say “This place is a wreck!”  After a major earthquake, in which our only damage was a hairline crack in ceiling plaster, I said, “On this of all days you are not allowed to say that.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She might say *"This place is a tip!"* or a "*dump*". (A tip being a rubbish dump, UK.) Or *"What a shambles!"*

I can think of several words, such as *pigsty*, but they are not actually idioms.

It is perhaps not "politically correct",  but *"It looks as though a bomb has gone off in here!"*  is a known saying.